# Sorting Firebase data on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently within my application, I am displaying a list of books from my Firebase database:

[image: Book List]

I would like to have an on click event which when the A-Z icon (shown in the image) is clicked, the list is sorted in Alphabetical order.

The code snippets show what I have so far:

```js
var myFirebase = new Firebase('https://project04-167712.firebaseio.com/object/Book/');

const ulList = document.getElementById('list');
const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('object');
const dbRefList = dbRefObject.child('Book');

var sort = document.querySelector('#sort');

sort.addEventListener("click", function() {
  //Where I want the sort event to go
  //So far I have this:
  dbRefList.orderByChild('book').on('child_added', snap => {
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerText = snap.val().book;
      li.id = snap.key;
      ulList.appendChild(li);

    });
    //This is taken directly from the child added but changed to orderByChild. 
    //It sorts the list but of course just re prints it below the unsorted list.
});

dbRefList.on('child_added', snap => {
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerText = snap.val().book;
      li.id = snap.key;
      ulList.appendChild(li);

    });

    dbRefList.on('child_changed', snap => {
      const liChanged = document.getElementById(snap.key);
      liChanged.innerText = snap.val().book;

    });

    dbRefList.on('child_removed', snap => {
      const liToRemove = document.getElementById(snap.key);
      liToRemove.remove();
      
    });
```

```html
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="sortContainer">
            <i id="sort" class="material-icons">sort_by_alpha</i>
        </div>
```

I know I should be using orderByChild - I'm just not sure how to implement. I tweaked the 'child_added' function to orderByChild which does sort the list, but prints it below the original sorted list:

[image: Sorted list]

Please could anyone advise what the most efficient way of sorting the list is onClick. At some point as well I want to be able to sort the list in reverse order - Z-A - So any help on that would be great as well.

Here is the screen shot of the firebase JSON file:[image: JSON]

Many thanks,
G

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal snippet of your JSON structure. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Added it @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Have you tried to clear the list just before adding new items? I guess that adding `ulList.innerHTML = ''` inside your click event listener will give you that.

Comment: Hi there Gustavo, This is something I have tried - I Thought I would give it a go a few days ago. However, it creates a weird glitch. When I click the sort button it sorts fine. But when I then try and add  a new book, it displays the new book twice. But when I refresh the page it shows it just the once. its very odd

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this part of your code:

```
dbRefList.orderByChild('book').on('child_added', snap => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = snap.val().book;
    li.id = snap.key;
    ulList.appendChild(li);
});
```

You are creating a new *li* again below the unsorted one. Clear the parent *list* and then append.

```
ulList.innerHTML = '';
```

Add this inside your sortEventListener function. It should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Anand, but as mentioned in my comment previously to you, this solution causes glitches in the application. Although it works, it messes with other elements of the application

Comment: Use some css to fix height of the list container and make it scrollable

Comment: This is not the problem. The JS that you have said to add messes with the the actual data and duplicates the books

Comment: It shouldn't. You are adding `ulList.innerHTML = ''` before `dbRefList.orderByChild('book').on('child_added', snap => {` right?

Comment: I am adding that yes. I don't suppose this may be the problem - All of this JS is wrapped up within the window.onload = function() {